# Using list with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i've a new question for you. My idea is to check if the price about the first link is <= about the first price that you can found in list`` prices = [90.70.90.20.50.80] '', and if it doesn't the code has to jump into the second link and checks if its price is <= about the second price in the list called prices etc ...

I've tried to do that, but this code check if the first price is> = about all the prices list. I'm using> = to see how many emails sends, and it send 7 mail instead 2

How can i fix that?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
import time

urls = ["https://www.amazon.it/Corsair-Vengeance-Memorie-Desktop-Prestazioni/dp/B0143UM4TC",
        "https://www.amazon.it/AMD-Ryzen-5-3600-Processori/dp/B07STGGQ18",
        "https://www.amazon.it/Apple-iPhone-Grigio-Siderale-Ricondizionato/dp/B07985C44N"]

prices =[90.70 , 90.20 , 50.80]
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}
all_product = []

def check_price():
    for url in (urls):
        soup  = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url,headers=headers).content,'lxml')
        title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True)    
        try:
            products = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()
            fix_string=products.replace(",",".")      
            converted_price=float(fix_string[0:5])    
            all_product.append(converted_price)
            #print(all_product)
            for price in (prices):
                if (converted_price>=price): 
                    #send email
        except AttributeError:
            print ("Price not found, check if the product has an exposed price")
    print(all_product)
```

Comment: "this code check if the first price is> = about all the prices list". That's because your inner loop traverses the price in the prices list. All you need is one loop in the `check_price` function. `for url, price in zip(urls, prices)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does now is that it fetches the price from each URL, and checks that price against **every price in prices list**.

What you want it is to check the n-th URL against n-th price. This can be achieved by either:

Zipping the two lists together:

```
urls = [
    "https://www.amazon.it/Corsair-Vengeance-Memorie-Desktop-Prestazioni/dp/B0143UM4TC",
    "https://www.amazon.it/AMD-Ryzen-5-3600-Processori/dp/B07STGGQ18",
    "https://www.amazon.it/Apple-iPhone-Grigio-Siderale-Ricondizionato/dp/B07985C44N",
]

prices =[90.70, 90.20, 50.80]
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}
all_product = []

def check_price():
    for url, price in zip(urls, prices):
        soup  = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True)    
        try:
            products = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()
            fix_string = products.replace(",", ".")      
            converted_price = float(fix_string[0:5])
            all_product.append(converted_price)
            if converted_price >= price: 
                # send email
        except AttributeError:
            print("Price not found, check if the product has an exposed price")
```

Or by adding the prices as part of your url list:

```
urls_and_prices = [
    ("https://www.amazon.it/Corsair-Vengeance-Memorie-Desktop-Prestazioni/dp/B0143UM4TC", 90.70),
    ("https://www.amazon.it/AMD-Ryzen-5-3600-Processori/dp/B07STGGQ18", 90.20),
    ("https://www.amazon.it/Apple-iPhone-Grigio-Siderale-Ricondizionato/dp/B07985C44N", 50.80),
]

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}
all_product = []

def check_price():
    for url, price in urls_and_prices:
        soup  = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True)    
        try:
            products = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()
            fix_string = products.replace(",", ".")      
            converted_price = float(fix_string[0:5])
            all_product.append(converted_price)
            if converted_price >= price: 
                # send email
        except AttributeError:
            print("Price not found, check if the product has an exposed price")
```

I think that the latter might be better for you, as it is easier to see the paired items from it, as they are on the same line together.